# Fitting a model with data that are truly "not applicable"

Tags: regression, missing-data, nonlinear-regression, fitting

What model-fitting methods are available for data sets that have values that are truly "not applicable"?

After reading about imputation, I've realized that my data set does not have "missing values" which can be imputed, since there are no logical imputation values for the missing data.

Let me explain further; I have a data set $\mathbf B$, which is a matrix of parameters of a surrogate model. A surrogate model is a simpler, statistical approximation of a more complex model. Both the surrogate model and the complex model describe a system in the real world, which has unknown parameters $\mathbf x$. To find these parameters, the complex model can be simulated with many different parameter values, in an attempt to find the values that minimize the error between the output of the complex model and the measured behaviour of the real system. However, the complex model might be costly to simulate, so instead, a faster *surrogate* of the complex model is trained to replace it; the parameters of the trained surrogate model are found in the matrix $\mathbf B$.

For each observation $\mathbf i$ of $\mathbf B$, a parameter value $b_{j,i}$ is recorded only if the corresponding unknown parameter $\mathbf{x_j}$ is correlated with the response vector of the complex model $\mathbf{y_{cmplx,i}}$.

For example, consider this reduced example of $\mathbf B$ with four parameter vectors $\mathbf{b_0}$ (the intercept) and $\mathbf{b_1}$, $\mathbf{b_2}$, and $\mathbf{b_3}$, corresponding with parameters $\mathbf{x_1}$, $\mathbf{x_2}$, and $\mathbf{x_3}$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{b_0} & \mathbf{b_1} & \mathbf{b_2} & \mathbf{b_3} \\ \hline
 0 & 4 &  & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
 1 & 2 & 1 & & \\ \hline
 2 & 3 & 4 & & 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}

If we only look at observation $\mathbf i$ = $\mathbf 0$, we see that $\mathbf{b_1}$ has a missing value. This missing value stems from the fact that sampled values of $\mathbf{x_1}$ were uncorrelated with the complex response $\mathbf{y_{cmplx,0}}$ and were excluded from the fit, leaving simply $\mathbf{y_{cmplx,0}} = b_0 + b_2 \mathbf{x_2} + b_3 \mathbf{x_3}$ (if fitting a linear model). The resulting parameters of the fit would be $b_0 = 4$ , $b_2 = 2$ , and $b_3 = 3$.

---

Now going back to the explanation at the beginning of the post, the matrix $\mathbf B$ (our surrogate model) can be used to make a prediction of the "measured" response of our real system. However, what's more interesting is that the coefficients from regressing $\mathbf B$ onto the "measured" response vector $\mathbf{y_{meas}}$ are in fact an estimation of the unknown parameters of our real system!

There is a wrinkle in our plans though. Every observation in $\mathbf B$ has at least one N.A value, so a simple regression fit is not possible.

My objective is therefore to find a model-fitting method that can essentially "ignore" the missing values, so that when $\mathbf B$ is fitted to $\mathbf{y_{meas}}$, the estimated coefficients are as close as possible to those that would be estimated via gradient descent (GD). To elaborate, GD would find the coefficients that minimize the sum over all observations of the squared error between the $\mathbf i$th value of the $\mathbf{y_{meas}}$ vector and the prediction of the surrogate model at observation $\mathbf i$ (where only the relevant parameter vectors are included).

Taking our example above again, gradient descent would solve for the $\beta$ coefficients that minimize the following sum of squared errors:

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{arg \; min_{\beta}}(
&(y_{meas,0} - (b_{0,0} + \beta_2 b_{2,0} + \beta_3 b_{3,0}))^2 + \\
&(y_{meas,1} - (b_{0,1} + \beta_1 b_{1,1}))^2 + \\
&(y_{meas,2} - (b_{0,2} + \beta_1 b_{1,2} + \beta_3 b_{3,2}))^2) \\
\end{aligned}$$

Again, these $\beta$ coefficients are estimations of our unknown parameters $\mathbf x$. I've successfully managed to estimate coefficients through this gradient descent method with a linear model fit. However, my unknown parameters $\mathbf x$ actually have a non-linear relationship with the measured response, and gradient descent with any non-linear model I have tried is way too costly.

Comment: Could you explain to us what "truly not applicable" means?  An example might help.

Comment: I think I've improved the question quite a bit. Please let me know if it makes more sense, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't "excluded from the fit" be exactly the same thing as setting the coefficient to zero?

Comment: I've thought about that; however, when regressing $\mathbf B$ on to $\mathbf{y_{true}}$, wouldn't a bunch of zeros in $\mathbf B$ bring the estimated coefficients towards zero? In other words, the slopes would be erroneously flattened?

Comment: Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is unclear and questionable.  Could you explain what this regression of a "true" response vector against a matrix of *estimated* parameters is intended to accomplish? It sounds like you have reversed the roles of explanatory variables and response variables here, because "true" implies there's no error, but there certainly is potential error in $B.$

Comment: I am calibrating the unknown parameters of a building energy model (such as wall insulation) through two steps: (1) a surrogate model is trained to predict the simulated energy consumption of the building energy model, by sampling values of my unknown building parameters, $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$: $y_{sim} \sim x_1 + x_2 + x_3$; (2) the trained surrogate model is then used to infer the "true"/"calibrated" values of the unknown building parameters by minimizing the error between the surrogate model and the "true"/"actual" energy consumption of the building that is modelled.

Comment: I'm afraid you lost me at "predict the simulated energy consumption."  Simulated how? Why? It would help to know the overall objective rather than having an account of how you are presently trying to achieve it.  It sounds likely that a different approach altogether might solve your problem better than trying to make the present approach work.

Comment: Here is an article I wrote on this technique, where the surrogate model is a neural network: [Building energy model calibration using a surrogate neural network](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378778823002876). I know it's asking a lot for you to go through it, but the technique is best explained there. I will continue to try to come up with a better way to explain it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146843/discussion-between-florent-h-and-whuber).

Comment: @whuber. I've revamped the question, removing the notion of "simulated" and "true" and elaborating on surrogate modelling. Could you please let me know if the question makes more sense now?